# Accessing Attributes using Tweepy

Tags: twitter, attributes, tweepy

When I am using tweepy, I can't seem to grab specific attributes out of the tweet grabber.

After authentication (not posting the codes for obvious reasons), this is the code I have so far:

```
user = api.get_user(username='Redistrict')
tweet = api.get_tweets(ids="74820061")
tweet3200 = api.get_users_tweets(id="74820061", exclude="retweets", tweet_fields="text")
```

This grabs the tweets from user 'Redistrict' which can be seen using `print(tweet3200)`

However, the problem occurs when I try `print(tweet3200.text)` (or any other attempt to call an attribute such as `print(user.username)` or `print(tweet.id)`). It gives me the error `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'text'`. I've seen this error after many attempts at fixing it ... and it's become quite annoying as I don't know what I am doing wrong.

For reference, I've consulted the Twitter dev page https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets#tab0 and it lists all of the attributes I attempt to call as valid response fields.

What's also rather strange is that when I originally was fiddling around with the different commands, I was able to access the attributes by using `print(user.username)` or `print(user.id)`. However, after changing and slimming down the authentication to just OAuth2, it no longer works.

I am a rather novice coder experimenting with APIs, so any and all accessible answers are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tweets are in the `Response.data` dict (see the Response documentation [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/response.html)).

And by the way, the `text` attribute is always returned, there is no need to ask for it.

```py
response = api.get_users_tweets(id="74820061", exclude="retweets")

for tweet in reponse.data:
    print(tweet.text)
```